# Right & Left Img Borders Being Cut Off on Mobile - Force Mobile to Display Images + Borders?

Tags: html, css, mobile, border, blogger

I have a series 8.5" x 11" @ 72ppi magazine pages exported from InDesign as jpegs that I wish to display within Blogger posts. I want to display a 1 pixel border around each of these images so the edges of the pages are more easily discerned. I am testing the mobile version of the Blogger site in Chrome's emulator.

The images are correctly be resized to fit the mobile device; however the right and left borders are being cut off. Sometimes the page will load with one border showing, but the opposing border is then 2 pixels off screen. Sometimes when I reload the blog, or change devices, the borders might appear correctly, but then start not appearing once again. How do I make sure the images are correctly resized with the border on each side

```
.post-body-container img {
border:1px solid #000000;
padding:0px;
width: 612px;
height:100%;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding padding so that it pushes the images from the edges enough that the borders show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to not have a fixed width if you want responsiveness to work.

```
.post-body-container {
max-width: 100%;
}

.post-body-container img {
border:1px solid #000000;
padding:0px;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
}
```

Example (try resizing the page to see the image size changing): https://codepen.io/felipefreitag/pen/EbXxjx

Further reading:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. I slightly modified the supplied code by adding a margin. This works for all the devices in the Chrome emulator except for the two Nexus devices, which keep scaling the images so as to cut off the left and rights borders. This could be a problem with the emulator. Another solution which works on all devices is to add a 1 pixel border graphic inside InDesign and export the images with a 1 pixel border.

```
.post-body-container {
max-width: 100%;
}

.post-body-container img {
border:1px solid #000000;
margin:2px;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
}
```